# How to get the auto-incremented ID for a row once you insert values using php?

Tags: php, insert, information-retrieval

I have a MySQL database and am using httpRequest to connect it with my Android Application. I have a php file that would insert values via httpPost and the table it is inserting to have an auto-incrementing id to keep each row unique.

What I want to do is to be able to insert values via php and get an ID of the inserted row which I would then use for another insert query. Any ideas how to do this via php?

Here is my current code:

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will insert an order request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['table_ID']) && isset($_POST['MenuBook']) && isset($_POST['order_status'])&& isset($_POST['order_date'])&& isset($_POST['order_receipt'])) {

    $tableID = $_POST['table_ID'];
    $menuBook = $_POST['MenuBook'];
    $order_status = $_POST['order_status'];
    $order_date = $_POST['order_date'];
    $order_receipt = $_POST['order_receipt'];

    // inlude db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/DBConnect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql inserting a new row
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO orderdb(table_ID,MenuBook,order_status,order_date,order_receipt) VALUES('$table_ID', '$menuBook', '$order_status','$order_date','$order_receipt')");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Order successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: *Obligatory:* The `mysql_*` functions will be [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated). It is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: ^^^^as true as it is, its getting a little tedious for regular S.O users to see it 10+ times a day

Comment: @Dagon I, personally, find it more tedious to see people not reading the big red box on every page of the `ext/mysql` manual and still using it while they learn the basics of PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `mysql_insert_id` like shown below, though you really should convert to `mysqli` or `PDO`, which both have similar functions.

```
// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO orderdb(table_ID,MenuBook,order_status,order_date,order_receipt) VALUES('$table_ID', '$menuBook', '$order_status','$order_date','$order_receipt')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    $insert_id = mysql_insert_id($db);

    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Order successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
```

Answer (score 2):

After your insert query, use [mysql-insert-id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php).

```
<?php 
...
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO orderdb(table_ID,MenuBook,order_status,order_date,order_receipt) VALUES('$table_ID', '$menuBook', '$order_status','$order_date','$order_receipt')");
$last_ID = mysql_insert_id();
...
?>
```

From the docs for mysql_insert_id():

> The ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query on
>   success, 0 if the previous query does not generate an AUTO_INCREMENT
>   value, or FALSE if no MySQL connection was established.

Answer (score 2):

There is a function you can call that will return the id of the previous query on an auto increment column. Typically you call this whenever you insert or update and need the ID.

MySQL:
$id = mysql_insert_id();  // return id of last insert

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

MySQLi:
$id = $mysqli->insert_id

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 1):

After your query you can use `mysql_insert_id()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

But the mysql driver you're using is depreciated, so maybe you should use mysqli or pdo.

Answer (score 1):

```
used_id = mysql_insert_id($db);
```

PLease consider migrating to mysqli module, mysql_query is dangerous and opens doors to sql injections.